# FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Chatter Answers User is not allowed for this License Type

Tags: apex, visualforce, class

FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Chatter Answers User is not allowed for this License Type

On my test class, I am getting the following error.

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Chatter Answers User is not allowed for this License Type.: [UserPermissions] 
Stack Trace: Class.ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegTest.validateCreateUpdateUser: line 32, column 1
```

The class that does it is

```
@isTest
private class ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegTest {
  static testMethod void validateCreateUpdateUser() {
    User thisUser = [ select Id from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
    System.runAs ( thisUser ) {
      Auth.UserData userData = new Auth.UserData('testId', 'testFirst', 'testLast',
      'testFirst testLast', 'no-reply@salesforce.com', null, 'testuserlong', 'en_US', 'facebook',
      null, new Map<String, String>{'language' => 'en_US'});
      ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegistration reg = new ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegistration();
      Profile[] p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];
      User[] adminUser = [SELECT Id, Firstname, Lastname FROM User WHERE IsActive = true and ProfileId =: p[0].Id LIMIT 1];
      reg.setSiteAdminUserId(adminUser[0].Id);
      User newUser = reg.createUser(null, userData);
      System.assert(newUser != null, 'A new user should have been created');
      System.assertEquals(newUser.Firstname, 'testFirst', 'First name should have been same');
      System.assertEquals(newUser.Lastname, 'testLast', 'Last name should have been same');
      System.assertEquals(newUser.Email, 'no-reply@salesforce.com', 'Email should have been same');

      Contact c = new Contact();
      c.AccountId = (newUser.Username.split('@'))[0];
      c.LastName = 'contactLast';
      insert(c);

      newUser.profileId = p[0].Id;
      newUser.Alias = 'firstusr';
      newUser.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
      newUser.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
      newUser.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
      newUser.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
      newUser.ContactId = c.Id;

      insert(newUser);


      Auth.UserData updateUserData = new Auth.UserData('testId', 'updatedFirst', 'updatedLast',
      'updatedFirst updatedLast', 'no-reply@new.salesforce.com', null, 'testuserlong', 'en_US', 'facebook',
      null, new Map<String, String>{'language' => 'en_US'});
      reg.updateUser(newUser.Id, null, updateUserData);

      User dbUser =  [SELECT Id, Firstname, Lastname, Email FROM User WHERE Id = :newUser.Id];
      System.assertEquals(dbUser.Firstname, 'updatedFirst', 'First name should have been updated');
      System.assertEquals(dbUser.Lastname, 'updatedLast', 'Last name should have been updated');
      System.assertEquals(dbUser.Email, 'no-reply@new.salesforce.com', 'Email should have been updated');
    }
  }
}
```

I think this is related to some permission with the profile "System Administrator".  Any idea which permission needs to be enabled the user?

Comment: This is listed as known issue on [salesforce](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008ZX2AAM)